# React - state won't update

Tags: reactjs, state

i am building small react app and i have strange situation that state won't update. Here is example:

```
class App extends Component {

constructor() {
  super();

  this.state = {
    locale: 'de',
    countryList: [],
    fetchInProgress: true,
    serverError: {},
    person: {
      salutation: '',
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      birthDate: '',
      nationality: '',
      address: '',
      zipCode: '',
      city: '',
      country: '',
      mobileNumber: '',
      email: '',
      correspondanceLanguage: '',
    }
  };
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
    fetchInProgress: false
  }),()=>console.log('State updated', this.state)
}
```

}

I tried also using other approaches:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const temp = {...this.state};
  temp.fetchInProgress = false;
  this.setState(temp),()=>console.log('State updated', this.state)
}

componentDidMount() {
  const temp = {...this.state};
  temp['fetchInProgress'] = false;
  this.setState(temp),()=>console.log('State updated', this.state)
}
```

But never gets state updated. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have syntax errors in all of your approaches. Note that `setState()` has the following format:

```
setState(updater, callback)
```

where `updater` can either be a function or an object and where `callback` is a function.

---

Starting with your initial approach:

```
this.setState({
  fetchInProgress: false
}),()=>console.log('State updated', this.state)
```

should instead be:

```
this.setState({
  fetchInProgress: false
},()=>console.log('State updated', this.state))
```

---

The other code is correct until, again, you get to the `setState()` part:

```
this.setState(temp),()=>console.log('State updated', this.state)
```

should instead be:

```
this.setState(temp,()=>console.log('State updated', this.state))
```

Comment: Thank you Chris!  4 eyes are always better than 2 :)